Phones disconnect from router when port forwarding UDP
I have a Linksys router and eufy security system.
My eufy cameras' live feed (including doorbell) weren't sending data to the app when I was away from home, which I reported to their support line. Their suggestion was to ensure TCP ports 443 and 80 were open, and UDP ports 0-65535 (seems a big range to me).
When the rules are set up, my mobile and my wife's show the network as 'connected without internet'. I don't understand ports, is it that the phones' requests are getting forwarded to the camera hub instead of to the internet? My laptop is still connected fine.
The rules I set up in Linksys port forwarding were as follows:
Single Port Forwarding



Application
External Port
Internal Port
Protocol
IP Address




Eufy
443
443
TCP
192.168.1.71



Port Range forwarding



Application
Start-End Port
Protocol
IP Address




Eufy
0-65535
UDP
192.168.1.71




They want you to open every UDP port? I wouldn't do this if I were you. Did they provide a valid reason?

No offence, but you say you are a system admin in your profile, but don't know how basic internet routing works? I would recommend doing some research. What is a port is a good starting point.

A reasonable research effort is to check each rule separately and see if one of them alone causes the problem. So, which one? Each? Or does the problem occur only when the two rules work together?

@FrankThomas Most routers I've seen, the static port forwarding rules only apply after dynamic conntrack flow-based forwarding, so e.g. a packet that's recognized as a reply to port 12345 will always go to the correct host despite the custom rule. It's the default behavior for iptables and what allows the 'DMZ' feature to work.

The reason that your devices can't connect to the internet is because, as pointed out by a comment, your rules are forwarding all incoming UDP traffic to the Eufy camera hub, instead of it's intended device destination, essentially stopping any device from using any UDP port.
The remedy is to pick a random UDP port in the 49152 to 65535 range, that no other device uses, and create a rule that assigns WAN traffic to that port only. Then there won't be any port conflict.

My guess as to why your laptop was unaffected is maybe because it was already in a session when you changed these router rules; did you change the rules on the router admin panel from your laptop?

"This means that any requests from your mobile device are being forwarded to the Eufy camera hub, instead of being routed to the internet" – These requests come from the LAN side, do I get it right? How does the port forwarding rule affect them? Normally the rule should only matter for requests coming in on the WAN interface. What am I missing?

@KamilMaciorowski You're probably right, but I suspect something called "NAT reflection" is reflecting incoming traffic from the WAN back to the LAN, which in this case, my explanation could apply.

And also, I think the OP might be slightly confusing common terminology as well. They don't entirely understand what they are doing, therefore they haven't completely explained the situation well. and this is just my bets guess, I could definitely be wrong.

The redirection of the TCP port is something one would normally do when exposing a server to the Internet; it should not affect the ability of devices in LAN to reach the outside world. I wonder if redirecting all UDP ports may have crippled DNS or something.

@KamilMaciorowski Well then my answer no longer applies; I did not realise that the OP actually opened every UDP port. I thought that was just the recommendation! That would definitely be the issue, no doubt.

@KamilMaciorowski I was originally wrong, due to my wrong assumptions. Please see my revised answer.

@security_paranoid you're right on all counts. I own the router so am de facto admin just because there's no one handy who knows any better (it's just my home setup) ... and I was trying to follow advice given from Anker (owns eufy). Can't believe they advised me to open up every port. I've turned off the rule obviously and done some more research per the link you advised. One question; you recommended using 'one port between 49152 to 6553 range' how do you know that's the range I should be looking in?

@SpencerBarnes no worries, and to answer your question, mostly prior knowledge/experience, but I would also be very surprised if any ports within that range have a legitimate service running open. In fact, test it: on windows run netstat -ab and look for “LISTENING”, on linux run netstat -tuln: I would bet money there’s no open ports in that range- after you closed everyone, obviously!!

@SpencerBarnes sorry, but please let me clarify: I made a little typo in my answer, the actual recommended random port range is 49152 to 65535, not to 6553, like I accidentally said. There are plenty of legitimate services that run about port 6553 (e.g. 8080- HTTP proxy.)
